# ent go not enough arguments in call to field.UUID have (string) want (string, driver.Valuer) exit status 1

Tags: go

im trying to generate my existing plsql db using ent and entimport https://entgo.io/blog/2021/10/11/generating-ent-schemas-from-existing-sql-databases/#run-entimport

although i get the following error:

**go generate ./ent**

> entc/load: load schema dir:
> /home/kay/powerlevel/backend/ent/schema/authentication.go:19:276: not
> enough arguments in call to field.UUID
> have (string)
> want (string, driver.Valuer) exit status 1 ent/generate.go:3: running "go": exit status

**/ent/schema/authentication.go**

```
// Code generated by entimport, DO NOT EDIT.

package schema

import (
    "entgo.io/ent"
    "entgo.io/ent/dialect/entsql"
    "entgo.io/ent/schema"
    "entgo.io/ent/schema/edge"
    "entgo.io/ent/schema/field"
    "github.com/google/uuid"
)

type Authentication struct {
    ent.Schema
}

func (Authentication) Fields() []ent.Field {
    return []ent.Field{field.UUID("id", uuid.UUID{}), field.String("type"), field.String("service_id"), field.String("session_id"), field.String("password"), field.Time("created_at"), field.Time("updated_at").Optional(), field.Time("deleted_at").Optional(), field.UUID("user_id").Optional(uuid.UUID{})}
}
func (Authentication) Edges() []ent.Edge {
    return []ent.Edge{edge.From("user", User.Type).Ref("authentications").Unique().Field("user_id")}
}
func (Authentication) Annotations() []schema.Annotation {
    return []schema.Annotation{entsql.Annotation{Table: "authentication"}}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks Like entimport is not a perfect package after all.
if you see in the return statement of your Field() function at last
The Code is like this `, field.UUID("user_id").Optional(uuid.UUID{})`
Which should be `, field.UUID("user_id",uuid.UUID{}).Optional()`

in this entimport has generated wrong code so you have to change it also you should not use entimport package for converting database schema to ent code
it's not perfect package you need to change the code according to your need

you can do one thing generate code in a different folder and then change the necessary code like relationships and data-types are not properly generated by entimport so you have to change them every time you generate code with ent import.
then put that generated and edited code into your project this will also reduce writing whole code on your own and you also have backup of the code in which you have done your changes. so every time you use entimport you should use it in different folder then your project and then make necessary changes and replace only latest changed file in your project.
it's a hassle but it is what it is.

may be it gets fixed in later versions

Comment: there are also some other problems like entimport doesn't support bit data-type of mysql